# Running javascript in firefox gives error

Tags: javascript, firefox

I was reading about bookmarklets and created this for removing elements from a webpage,
I got wrote this bookmarklet by reading a few web pages and don't know much about javascript.

```
javascript: (() => {
const arr = ['div.w3-col', 'div.footer'];
const prop = ['display' 'none', 'important'];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
document.getElementsByTagName(arr[i])[0].style.setProperty(prop); 
}
```

When I run this in firefox console it gives me following error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
note: [ opened at line 3, column 11
```

What should I do next?

> ps I know I can use stylus for this

Comment: missing a , after 'display'

Comment: You mention firefox in the question and the tags, but this looks like a problem that is **not** specific to Firefox. Why call it out in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*edit:*

the error because `prop` not valid array, it missing comma then the `.setProperty()` need 3 arguments not an array

```
.setProperty(prop[0], prop[1], prop[2])
```

`div.w3-col` is not valid Tag name it css selector, so use below

`.querySelectorAll`

```
document.querySelectorAll(arr[i])[0].style.setProperty(prop[0], prop[1], prop[2]);
```

or `.querySelector`

```
document.querySelector(arr[i]).style.setProperty(prop[0], prop[1], prop[2]);
```

Comment: While this is true, it is not the cause of the error the question is asking about

Comment: So I was inherently wrong in my approach, thankyou. And @Quentin this did remove the error when running this script.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot a comma between `'display'` and `'none'`.

So, the code should be something like

```js
javascript:(() => {
    const arr = ['div.w3-col', 'div.footer'];
    const prop = ['display', 'none', 'important'];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName(arr[i])[0].style.setProperty(prop);
    }
})()
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev — The downvote arrow is marked "This is not useful". The answer should be a comment. There was *already* a comment which explained how to fix the problem. Make your own judgement.